# Django ORM ignore FilteredRelation condition

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

For some unknown reason condition in FilteredRelation seems to be ignored

```
annotations["passport_index"] = FilteredRelation("countrypassportindex", condition=Q(passport_index__year=2020))
queryset = self.settings.base_model.objects.annotate(**annotations).values(*values_orm_keys)
```

Here's `queryset.query` field value

```
SELECT
    "countries_countrytotaltradevalue"."value",
    "countries_countrytotaltradevalue"."year",
    "countries_countrymilitaryexpenses"."value",
    "countries_countrymilitaryexpenses"."year",
    "countries_countryeconomicfreedomindex"."value",
    "countries_countryeconomicfreedomindex"."year",
    "countries_countrypayingtaxesindex"."value",
    "countries_countrypayingtaxesindex"."year",
    "countries_countrysuiciderate"."value",
    "countries_countrysuiciderate"."year",
    "countries_countrypassportindex"."value",
    "countries_countrypassportindex"."year"
FROM "countries_country"
LEFT OUTER JOIN "countries_countrytotaltradevalue"
    ON ("countries_country"."id" = "countries_countrytotaltradevalue"."country_id")
LEFT OUTER JOIN "countries_countrymilitaryexpenses"
    ON ("countries_country"."id" = "countries_countrymilitaryexpenses"."country_id")
LEFT OUTER JOIN "countries_countryeconomicfreedomindex"
    ON ("countries_country"."id" = "countries_countryeconomicfreedomindex"."country_id")
LEFT OUTER JOIN "countries_countrypayingtaxesindex"
    ON ("countries_country"."id" = "countries_countrypayingtaxesindex"."country_id")
LEFT OUTER JOIN "countries_countrysuiciderate"
    ON ("countries_country"."id" = "countries_countrysuiciderate"."country_id")
LEFT OUTER JOIN "countries_countrypassportindex"
    ON ("countries_country"."id" = "countries_countrypassportindex"."country_id")
```

You can see that inside `LEFT OUTER JOIN ... ON ("countries_country"."id" = "countries_countrypassportindex"."country_id")` there is no `"countries_countrypassportindex"."year" = 2019`

Comment: Do you have any annotation that uses "passport_index" ? Doing F("passport_index__SOME_FIELD") for instance ? I pretty the FilteredRelation will be optimized out otherwise since if you're using it only for filter purposes, Django expectes you to use the .filter method

Comment: @Alombaros This code works fine
`annotations[cleaned_name] = FilteredRelation(orm_key, condition=Q(**{orm_key_year: model.get_latest_available_data_year()}),)`
Without filter clause
`
queryset = Country.objects.annotate(**annotations).values(
            *components_values_list
        )
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

String `passport_index` should be in `values_orm_keys`